# How to load an assembly as reflection-only in a new AppDomain?

Tags: .net, powershell, .net-assembly, appdomain

I'm experienced in C# but relatively unfamiliar with the concepts of `AppDomain` and the like. Anyway, I'm trying to get an assembly to load in a reflection-only context so I can grab all of its namespaces. Here is the code I have right now (warning: PowerShell):

```
function Get-Namespaces($assembly)
{
    $assemblyClass = [Reflection.Assembly]
    $winmdClass = [Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeMetadata]
    $domain = [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain

    # Since desktop .NET can't work with winmd files,
    # we have to use the reflection-only APIs and preload
    # all the dependencies manually.
    $appDomainHandler =
    {
        Param($sender, $e);
        $assemblyClass::ReflectionOnlyLoad($e.Name)
    }

    $winmdHandler =
    {
        Param($sender, $e)
        [string[]] $empty = @()
        $path = $winmdClass::ResolveNamespace($e.NamespaceName, $empty) | select -Index 0
        $e.ResolvedAssemblies.Add($assemblyClass::ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom($path))
    }

    # Hook up the handlers
    $domain.add_ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve($appDomainHandler)
    $winmdClass::add_ReflectionOnlyNamespaceResolve($winmdHandler)

    # Do the actual work
    $assemblyObject = $assemblyClass::ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom($assembly)
    $types = $assemblyObject.GetTypes()
    $namespaces = $types | ? IsPublic | select Namespace -Unique

    # Deregister the handlers
    $domain.remove_ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve($appDomainHandler)
    $winmdClass::remove_ReflectionOnlyNamespaceResolve($winmdHandler)

    return $namespaces
}
```

For some reason, when I'm running the function on assemblies like `System.Xaml` or `WindowsBase` I'm getting these errors:

```
Exception calling "ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "API restriction:
The assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\
Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Xaml.dll' has already loaded from a
different location. It cannot be loaded from a new location within the same
appdomain."
At C:\Users\James\Code\csharp\Shims.Xaml\generate.ps1:50 char:5
+     $assemblyObject = $assemblyClass::ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom($assembl ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileLoadException
```

So what I'd like to know is, how can I load the assembly in a new AppDomain? I checked [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25y1ya39(v=vs.110).aspx) but all I can find are methods like `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap`, which I can't/don't want to do since this is reflection-only.

**TL;DR:** How can I load assemblies in a reflection-only context in a new AppDomain? Both C# and PowerShell code samples welcome.

---

**EDIT:** [Here](https://gist.github.com/jamesqo/a1c737b4cfe9b0341ab4) is a GitHub gist of the script I've made, so others can repro the error/test changes.

Comment: The error says all ,the assembly is already loaded, skip those and grab them from System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()

Comment: If your goal is just to check the metadata then there are tons of alternatives such as Mono.Cecil. Involving new AppDomain and reflection is too complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got it:

```
function Load-AssemblyInNewAppDomain($assembly)
{
    $domain = [AppDomain]::CreateDomain("foo")
    $domain.DoCallback
    ({
        $loaded = [Reflection.Assembly]::Load($assembly)
    })
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work - it only echoes on the console the literal contents of DoCallback

Answer (score 1):

I got the same exception when loading multiple assemblies for different target frameworks, but with the same identity. My workaround was to do the assembly load in a separate .ps1, and call it via `CMD /C`, which creates a new AppDomain for each script call, thereby avoiding the exception.

*Parent *.ps1:*

```
& CMD /C powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "$PsScriptRoot\check-assembly.ps1" "net461\MyAssembly.dll"
# Check exit code...
& CMD /C powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "$PsScriptRoot\check-assembly.ps1" "netcoreapp3.1\MyAssembly.dll"
# Check exit code...
```

*check-assembly.ps1:*

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, HelpMessage="DLL file to check: ")] 
    [string]$dllFile
)

$ass = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$dllFile")
# Check $ass
```