# AppDomain.DoCallBack in Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell

I want to call load an assembly in another AppDomain, and call some functions in that assembly.
It works in C# code:

```
AppDomain otherDomain0 = AppDomain.CreateDomain("otherDomain");
otherDomain0.DoCallBack(new CrossAppDomainDelegate(MyCallBack));
static public void MyCallBack(){  }
```

while it doesn’t in powershell:

```
$domain = [AppDomain]::CreateDomain("foo")
$domain.DoCallback({ Write-Host “get called” })
```

The exception:

> Exception calling "DoCallBack" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot serialize
>   delegates over unmanaged function pointers, dynamic methods or methods
>   outside the delegate creator's assembly." At line:1 char:1 +
>   $domain.DoCallback({ + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo :
>   NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId : SerializationException

My powershell version is 5.0.10586.672. 
Do I miss something?

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249342/how-to-load-an-assembly-as-reflection-only-in-a-new-appdomain) @jame-ko could make it work.

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45602476/1165140

Answer (score 0):

"Based on the error, it won’t work. Powershell create dynamic methods when you use a script block as a delegate."
That's the response I get from a powershell expert.