# Reflection Assembly Errors in Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis, .net-assembly, windows-server-2012-r2

I have some Powershell code that takes the Apps running on an IIS server and finds the versions of .NET they are running.

```
$Apps = Get-WebApplication
foreach($App in $Apps) {
    $binLocation = "$($App.physicalPath)\bin"

    # get all dlls in bin folder
    $dllFolder = Get-Item -Path $binLocation
    $dlls = $dllFolder.GetFiles("*.dll")

    # analyze dll .net version
    $set = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[String]
    $dlls | ForEach-Object {
        $set.Add([Reflection.Assembly]::ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom("$binLocation\$($_.Name)").ImageRuntimeVersion) | Out-Null
    }

    # print all dll .NET version
    $App
        $set
}
```

However when I run this on my server I get 2 types of error;

```
Exception calling "ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "API restriction: The
assembly 'file:///D:\inetpub\wwwroot\OABS_ECRM\bin\WebGrease.dll' has already loaded from a 
different location. It cannot be loaded from a new location within the same appdomain."
At line:13 char:74
+         $set.Add([Reflection.Assembly]::ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom ("$binLocation\$($_.Name ...
+                                                                                ~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileLoadException
```

and,

```
Exception calling "ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or 
assembly 'file:///D:\inetpub\wwwroot\Tablet\bin\epengine.dll' or one of its dependencies. 
The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest."
At line:13 char:74
+         $set.Add([Reflection.Assembly]::ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom("$binLocation\$($_.Name ...
+                                                                                ~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadImageFormatException
```

I seem to get the .NET versions running on each app from the script but I was wondering what caused these errors and if they can be cleared. I need to solve this in powershell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load an assembly as reflection-only in a new AppDomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249342/how-to-load-an-assembly-as-reflection-only-in-a-new-appdomain)

Comment: I'm looking for a solution in powershell specifically

Answer (score 0):

Loading multiple DLLs with the same identity into the same AppDomain will give you the first exception.

See my workaround at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62379741/920618.